# Disable ECDSA SSH Host keys

Tags: macos, security, ssh, encryption

I would like to disable ECDSA SSH host keys.

I deleted the existing keys:

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key*
```

I uncomment ECDSA in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
$ grep -i ecdsa /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

But when I restart `sshd` the keys are re-generated

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
$ ls -l /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key*
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  480 Nov 16 14:57 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  162 Nov 16 14:57 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

Ideally, the system would not employ weak elliptic curves as ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 at all going forward.

How can I prevent `sshd` to regenerate the ECDSA keys?

Comment: See this relevant post:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/disabling-authentication-via-dsa-keys-in-openssh

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the hint. In the end, all the clean solutions involve a new version of OpenSSH. The trick in the question though seems to work

Comment: I’m curious why you want to disable this. What’s the benefit you are realizing or goal you’re trying to achieve by this? I would love to answer that question if you still have this requirement unsatisfied.

Comment: @bmike I would like to disable weak elliptic curves as ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution but substituting the key with empty files seems to work:

```
cd /etc/ssh/
sudo rm ssh_host_ecdsa_key
sudo touch ssh_host_ecdsa_key
sudo rm ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
sudo touch ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

The key is invalid and not used, but is not corrected/regenerate when starting up

Answer (score 0):

A quick one liner for blanking out host ECDSA keys:

```
sudo truncate -s 0 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key* && sudo chmod u-w /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key*
```

To prevent your sshd server from advertising "weak" ECDSA keys, you need to modify `/etc/sshd_config`

```
HostKeyAlgorithms -ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,-ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,-ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
```

Even better, another way of preventing your sshd server from advertising any "weak" keys would be to specify advertising only strong keys in `/etc/sshd_config`

```
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
```

Comment: I tried this and sshd would not restart, and did not generate new keys of any kind.  No harm --  I had made a quickie backup in a subdirectory.  Also, the config lines do not mention the ed25519 keys (no certs) that I would like to use.